# Htaccess Redirect 301 only value of a certain parameter

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I would like yo 301 redirect any instance with location=ako to location=akko

Exapmles
https://www.westgalil.org.il/evt/?location=ako
to
https://www.westgalil.org.il/evt/?location=akko

https://www.westgalil.org.il/ent/?ent-type=attractions&location=ako
to
https://www.westgalil.org.il/ent/?ent-type=attractions&location=akko

I tried this code but it didn't work

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location=ako(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?/$0?location=akko [R=301,L]

Comment: You will drop all other query arguments that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is a somewhat more general and more robust approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|(.*&))location=ako(?:(&.*)|$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1location=akko%3 [R=301]
```

Please note that I did not check this with a test setup, I only wrote it down to the best of my knowledge, you might have to tweak it a bit...

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).